# Terraform apply exit code on error

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I'm using Terraform as part of a Jenkins Pipeline. When `terraform apply` encounters an error, it does not return a non-zero exit code. When running into a problem on Jenkins, it does not stop the pipeline or mark the build as FAILURE.

If terraform encounters an error, I need the job to stop and not progress.

Looking at the [docs for `apply`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html), it doesn't look like I can provide a flag to return helpful exit codes. The [docs for `plan`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html) has a `-detailed-exitcode` flag, but doesn't look like that'll help me.

Comment: Would sidestepping the issue by running `terraform apply | tee /dev/tty | ( ! grep "Error applying plan" )` work? That will return 1 if the "Error applying plan" text is in the output. Let me know if that's a suitable answer for you, or if you're looking for a *more graceful* solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That would do the job, but it's a little more of a hack than what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this was not a real issue. My apologies. At the end of that shell script, it did an echo which is what was returning the non-zero status code. After I took that out, it worked as expected.

Comment: shouldn't jenkins fail is any command in 'execute shell' returns non-zero?